# TFS 2017 unable to login from inside the server

Tags: tfs

We have just upgraded to TFS 2017 from TFS 2013. We have changed the URL based on certificate issued to company.
eg. certificate is for *.xyz.com
So we changed TFS url from https://servername to https://tfs.xyz.com.
new url is working fine from everywhere, from other servers or even from local machines but not working from inside the app server where TFS is installed.
Continuously prompting to enter password but not taking password.
But when i try to connect to old url from inside server i.e. https://servername. It is working fine.

Any idea where the issue could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this, i have enabled all 3 kind of Authentication from Server.

Basic (ALT) 
Anonymous 
Windows

Once i have enabled all three, it is working fine now.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache files on your server, which should in `C:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache` (you could check the Cache File Folder in TFS Administration Console -- Application Tier).

Also, try to clean the folders under path `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`, and reset iis by clicking **Start** and select **Run**… to open the dialog box, then input **iisreset.exe** and click OK.

Comment: Tried, still issue is same. Cannot access changed URL from inside the server. I am able to access through localhost or server ip address but when i use new url (https://tfs.xyz,com). it is stuck at Authentication Dialogue Box. New URL works fine from outside Server.

Comment: How about deleting the account for the TFS server in Control Panel -> User Accounts-> Credentail manager.